# grouping in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Given a table of thousands of rows of data as shown in the sample below

```
Id  Date        SymbolId    NumOccs HighProjection  LowProjection   ProjectionTypeId
1   2014-04-09    28           45        1.0765        1.0519            1
2   2014-04-10    5            44        60.23         58.03             1
3   2014-04-11    29           77        1.026         1.0153            1
```

and a Class defined as

```
Public Class ProjectionPerformance
    Public symbolId As Integer
    Public Name as String
    Public Date as String       
    Public ActualRange as Decimal
End Class
```

I am trying to return the following for each symbolId;
The symbolId (from this table)
The symbol Name (from the symbols table)
The Actual Range (High Projection - Low Projection)

Can this be done in one query since i am essentially in need of a Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of ProjectionPerformance)) where the integer is the symbolId and the List is generated from the query?

**Updated:**
So as to be a little clearer, Here is what I'm doing so far but contains two LINQ iterations

```
Public Shared Function GetRangeProjectionPerformance(Optional daysToRetrieve As Integer = 100) As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of ProjectionPerformance))

Dim todaysDate As Date = DateTime.Now.Date
Dim lookbackDate As Date = todaysDate.AddDays(daysToRetrieve * -1)
Dim temp As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of ProjectionPerformance))


Using ctx As New ProjectionsEntities()
    Dim query = (From d In ctx.projections
                 Where d.SymbolId <= 42 AndAlso d.Date >= lookbackDate
                 Join t In ctx.symbols On d.SymbolId Equals t.Id
                 Let actualRange = d.HighProjection - d.LowProjection
                 Select New With {
                    d.Date,
                    d.SymbolId,
                    t.Name,
                    actualRange}).GroupBy(Function(o) o.SymbolId).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key)

    For Each itm In query
        Dim rpp As New ProjectionPerformance
        Dim rppList As New List(Of ProjectionPerformance)
        If itm.Value.Count > 0 Then
            For x As Integer = 0 To itm.Value.Count - 1
                Dim bb As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(itm.Value(x).SymbolId)
                With rpp
                    .SymbolId = bb
                    .ProjectionDate = itm.Value(x).Date.ToString()
                    .Name = itm.Value(x).Name
                    .ProjectedRange = itm.Value(x).actualRange
                End With
                rppList.Add(rpp)
            Next
        End If

        temp.Add(itm.Key, rppList)
    Next
End Using
Return temp
```

End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer in C#, but I think you'll get the gist of it anyway. Basically, you can group by `SymbolId`, build your object graph and then use `ToDictionary` using the `Key` to create `dictionary`.

```
var result = (From d In _projectionEntities.projections
                 Where d.SymbolId <= 42
                 group d by d.SymbolId into g
                 select new {
                         SymbolId = g.Key,
                           ProjectionPerformances = 
                                       g.Select(gg=>new ProjectionPerformance{
                                                   SymbolId = gg.SymbolId,
                                                   Name = gg.Symbol.Name,
                                                   rpDate = gg.Date.ToString(),
                                                   ActualRange = gg.HighProjection - gg.LowProjection
                                                  })
                      .ToDictionary(g=>g.SymbolId);
```

Comment: Ok that looks right. Ill work on converting to vb.Net

Comment: Your answer helped me come up with the correct answer, with a little help from a another poster on another question. In your version and my original the query gives me a casting to decimal error. But I'm good to go now. TY

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Dim Result = (From d In _ProjectionEntities.projections
             Join t In _projectionEntities.symbols On d.SymbolId Equals t.Id
             Where d.SymbolId <= 42
             Select New With {.SymbolID = d.SymbolID
                              .Date = d.Date
                              .Name = t.Name
                              .ActualRange = d.HighProjection - d.LowProjection})
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question posed in the post. I can already query for the full results of the class. It's putting it into the Dictioary in one LINQ query was the question.